# AppBarLayout and Toolbar invisible on Android 4.x

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I am using the new AppbarLayout and Toolbar from the v22 design support library. But they appear invisible on 4.x devices. Is this a known issue? How do I fix it?

Here's my XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:title="inSight Source"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

They're in a relativelayout. Moving them into a CoordinatorLayout did not fix the issue.

The AppbarLayout and Toolbar are there, since there is a 'shade' when you pull the underlying scrollview, but they are invisible.

My full layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/setting_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/setting_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:title="inSight Source" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/setting_bg_img"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/baseimg"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/setting_appbar" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/login_insight_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:typeface="roboto_thin"
            android:text="inSight Source"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/login_companion_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:typeface="roboto_thin"
            android:text="companion app"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_insight_label"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <!-- invisible view for margin -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/setting_card_driver"
            layout="@layout/include_setting_card" />

        <!-- invisible view for margin -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/setting_card_vehicle"
            layout="@layout/include_setting_card" />

        <!-- invisible view for margin -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#fff" >

            <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
                android:id="@+id/setting_info_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:typeface="roboto_regular"
                android:text="Deze instellingen kunt u aanpassen in inSight Source"
                android:textSize="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:textColor="@color/insight_antraciet"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setting_logout_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="LOG UIT"
            android:theme="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also tried placing the AppBarLayout in a CoordinatorLayout but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using a theme on the `AppBarLayout`? If you remove that your `Toolbar` will probably appear again. You can move the theme to the Toolbar:

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

**Edit**

Add this to your ImageView:

```
android:layout_below="@id/setting_appbar"
```

Your `ImageView` was above your `Toolbar` so that's why you couldn't see it. One other thing you could do is put the `Toolbar` at the bottom of the layout so it appears above the `ImageView`.

Comment: You are right, but that solution did not work. The bar is still invisible.

Comment: @TimKranen What is your primary color? Also try android before `actionBarSize` like this: `?android:attr/actionBarSize`. Perhaps you can send the entire layout so I can check it out?

Comment: I stripped the toolbar of all properties, gave it a static height and static color but that did not work. It's still invisible. I've posted my full layout.

Comment: @TimKranen See my answer, I edited it. The `ImageView` was above your `Toolbar` so that was the problem

Comment: This fixed the issue!! Thanks a lot! Do you know why 5.0+ did display it correctly?

Comment: @TimKranen Not sure, I would've thought it would be the same. But maybe 5.0+ puts the `AppBarLayout` on top or something. Glad this fixed it!